# Record text to speech audio

Tags: linux, windows, audio, android, text-to-speech

I want to generate an audio file given a text, epub or pdf file. As I don't know any program to do this on the computer I'm trying to record the audio of a program I use in the phone to listen to books. **If there is a simpler way of achieving this in the computer I would like to know.**

I use Moon+ Reader with Ivona voice, which sounds quite natural to me.
I use an Android 10 QKQ1.190825.002, MIUI 12.0.5. phone, a Windows 10 PC and a Linux Mint 20.1 laptop.

I've tried connecting a 3.5 mm aux cable to my phone and windows computer, then I go to Control Panel->Sound settings->Recording. I disable everything except the microphone, then on properties, I check Listen to this device. On levels I put the microphone at 50%. In advanced I uncheck Enable audio enhancements.

Then in audacity I go to edit->Preferences->Recording and check Software playthrough of input, and uncheck the rest.

Then I record the audio in audacity. **The problem I have with this method is that the recorded audio isn't as crisp as the one I listen directly from the phone.**

Comment: I use Linux eSpeak but I'm not sure if its quality is on par with current expectations as of 2022.

Answer (score 0):

Try this website https://www.naturalreaders.com/online/
There's also a software variant but I haven't tried it. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

> The problem I have with this method is that the recorded audio isn't as crisp as the one I listen directly from the phone.

Unfortunately, the "crispness" (as you describe it) is likely down to a combination of whatever your phone outputs through its audio jack, your PC's sound card and its speakers.

> If there is a simpler way of achieving this in the computer I would like to know.

Ivona TTS voices were an Amazon product (though I believe they have since been superseded by the [Amazon Polly](https://aws.amazon.com/polly/) cloud service). This means that they can be part of different text reading software.

For instance, if you Google "[ivona voice](https://www.google.com/search?q=ivona+voice)", the first result is currently for a desktop reader application called "[TextAloud4](https://nextup.com/ivona/)" which can be purchased with Ivona voices.

The link above also seems to allow purchase of individual SAPI 5 compatible Ivona voices (to be clear, other websites offer these voices individually as well). This means that you could (theoretically) find a desktop reader application supporting SAPI 5 voices that you knew had the features you wanted (such as e.g. [Balabolka](http://www.cross-plus-a.com/balabolka.htm)) and potentially use the purchased voice with that.